# Powershell decompress byte array takes lot of time

Tags: powershell, compression

I'm passing a 30MB of compressed UTF-8 encoded binary array to this powershell function. It's taking more than 30 minutes to process and crashes the powershell without giving output. Any advice on how to make it faster?

```
function Get-DecompressedByteArray {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [byte[]] $byteArray = $(Throw("-byteArray is required"))
    )
    Process {
        Write-Verbose "Get-DecompressedByteArray"
        $input = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream( , $byteArray )
        $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
        $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $input, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        $gzipStream.CopyTo( $output )
        $gzipStream.Close()
        $input.Close()
        [byte[]] $byteOutArray = $output.ToArray()
        Write-Output $byteOutArray
    }
}
```

Calling the function

```
$result=Get-DecompressedByteArray -byteArray $res.content
```

Comment: First of all: you do not return array, but each byte separately.

Comment: Could you provide a file for testing pls (download-link)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C# code with Add-Type is up to 4 times faster than powershell code. I've tested here with a 5 MB size gzip file. Perhaps you should use the C# code in your powershell script to get more performance.

```
Add-Type -typedef @"
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;

    namespace myGzip
    {
        public static class Decompressor
        {
            public static byte[] Decompress(string filePath)
            {
                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream(data))
                {
                    using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
                            return resultStream.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

"@

function Get-DecompressedByteArray {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [byte[]] $byteArray = $(Throw("-byteArray is required"))
    )
    Process {
        Write-Verbose "Get-DecompressedByteArray"
        $input = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream( , $byteArray )
        $output = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
        $gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $input, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)
        $gzipStream.CopyTo( $output )
        $gzipStream.Close()
        $input.Close()
        [byte[]] $byteOutArray = $output.ToArray()
        Write-Output $byteOutArray
    }
}

# Powershell
(Measure-Command {

    $inBytes  = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("D:\test.gz");
    $bytes    = Get-DecompressedByteArray -byteArray $inBytes


}).Milliseconds
$bytes.Length

# C#
(Measure-Command {

    $bytes = [myGzip.Decompressor]::Decompress("D:\test.gz")

}).Milliseconds
$bytes.Length
```

Comment: Just pick you one .gz file for testing from the Internet, e. g. here: http://hgdownload-test.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/mm9/liftOver/

Comment: Thanks a lot @f6a4 !! you are my life safer!